# Todos for getting better at UX

Tags: ux-designer

I have been developing at the front end for over 4 years and it's been fun till now. I find UX job particularly interesting. I use HTML5, JS, jQuery, CSS3, Bootstrap libraries as my daily tools. But the world is moving faster than I can develop. :)

I would like to know about some more stuff so that I could keep up the pace and sharpen my skills. In short, get better at UX.

Responses about new technologies or using new ways in old technologies are all welcome. Thank you !

Comment: As much as I hate to do this for someone just starting out in UX, your question is too broad for this format.

Comment: User Experience is not about the code and technologies. If you want to learn more about UX, you will need to learn about the skills and specialisations that work under the UX umbrella, e.g. Usability Testing, Information Architecture Design, Interaction Design, Visual Design, etc. Each of these UX disciplines has a basis in human behaviour science, because ultimately we want to design solutions for real people.

Comment: @Splatz Thanks for the insight brother. It would be great if you could suggest more about Visual design.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry to have bothered you with my question but I really want to learn these stuff. Learning is cursed with asking stupid questions. :)

I would like to narrow it down and rephrase my question for you, What technologies/software tools would be particularly useful to learn, from the view point of responsive web designing ? Other than the one I have already mentioned in my question ?

Comment: @Ayan, Sorry but this is still to broad for this format - ux.stackexchange.com is geared towards finding specific, testable answers to specific UX problems. It is not good for soliciting 'opinion' or asking about software and tools that quickly outdate. As a personal tip, UX is more about understanding what your users hope to achieve with your product and helping them do that as painlessly as possible while still meeting the requirements for the business to be successful - as has already been said, it is not about code.

Comment: @Ayan You may have better luck on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/topic/User-Experience), if you're still looking for resources. As I write this, the top question in the UX category happens to be "What UX blogs, resources, or books does a prospective User Experience design leader need to read?" and it has 16 answers. [Marina Yalanska's](https://www.quora.com/What-UX-blogs-resources-or-books-does-a-prospective-User-Experience-design-leader-need-to-read/answer/Marina-Yalanska) lines up the best with my experience.

Comment: This site has most of the general knowledge to move you in the right direction. https://uxdesign.cc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some excellent books you could read:

- About Face 3 - Alan Cooper
- Information Architecture for the Web and Beyond - Peter Morville &
  Jorge Arango
- Undercover User Experience Design - Cennydd Bowles & James Box
- Measuring the User Experience - Tom Tullis & Bill Albert
- Designing Web Interfaces - Bill Scott & Theresa Neil

Visual Design is huge subject and there are just too many great books to list here. The Designer's Web Handbook by Patrick McNeil is a good starting point.

Comment: Excellent !! Looks like a really nice list of books to be friends with. Thank you very much for your suggestions..